# What are Ethereum Genesis transactions?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, defi, privacy, tornado-cash

I recently came across these transactions on Ethereum that don't have a typical transaction hash. They are sent by a wallet named "**GENESIS**," which is not associated with any specific address or contract. Interestingly, it appears that these transactions cannot be easily traced back to their origin.

[etherscan.io/address/0x9374869d4a9911ee1eaf558bc4c2b63ec63acfdd](https://etherscan.io/address/0x9374869d4a9911ee1eaf558bc4c2b63ec63acfdd)

[image]

After doing some research on how to execute these types of transactions, I discovered a dapp called [private.cash](https://private.cash/). It seems to provide a way to execute these transactions on Ethereum, with the main aim being anonymity. However, I would appreciate if someone could explain the underlying mechanism and workings behind this process.

Comment: this? https://twitter.com/BeaconCash/status/1678121797466873856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, Genesis transactions are the very first transactions that take place in the Ethereum network. They are different from regular transactions because they don't have a typical transaction hash. Instead, they have a **genesis hash** that cannot be traced back. Genesis is not a specific **contract or address**; it's actually a type of data represented in a hexadecimal format.

Like in the case of your dapp [beacon.cash](https://beacon.cash). The process of creating Genesis transactions involves generating a hexadecimal data and a commitment hash for the recipient's address. These data are then sent through a router, such as the Uniswap V3 router in your case. Once the transaction is sent, the deposited amount becomes untraceable and anonymous because the source of the transaction cannot be identified.

[image]

Comment: It isn't anonymous. It is the starting point of the Ethereum World State. Why are you mention Uniswap? It didn't exist when the Ethereum blockchain was created.

Comment: I know! But I was clearly explaining the answer to the question. Read the question he asked about how these transactions are executed from his mentioned dApp. This is done by using a Uniswap router to send the receipt data to the genesis, making the deposit anonymous.

Comment: There's nothing anonymous on Ethereum. Uniswap is a contract and you can trace transfers. The genesis block was created at the beginning of the blockchain history and it cannot be modified, so there will never be new "genesis transactions".